# run manage.py where manage.py is not present?

Tags: django, manage.py

manage.py is under `project_home/mysite/mysite/bin/manage.py`

I did it following a recommendation from some book.
The point is it's rather hard to execute `python manage.py something` as it stands since I have to move to the directory or type the directory path leading to it.

Is there a convenient way to call manage.py in this setup?

Comment: r u using ubuntu teminal to run manage.py??

Comment: ubuntu terminal? I'm running on ubuntu, and I'm using a ssh terminal. Not sure if there's something specific you had in mind.

Comment: You can make an alias, or export an environment variable and use it, no ?

Comment: what's the author writing about the benefit of putting manage.py into /bin/? However, you can still use django-admin.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call `manage.py` anywhere, you can use `Django-manage.py-anywhere`. As package description says you can  run manage.py commands from any directory of your Django project.
See more here: https://github.com/timonweb/Django-manage.py-anywhere